# TinyMCE - In Firefox, value doesn't submit

Tags: javascript, firefox, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE for all my textareas, so that user can enter any formatted text. Everything works fine in Google Chrome, but in Mozilla Firefox, the fields behave unexpectedly. The values from the textareas doesn't get submitted unless I focus-out and focus-in again into the fields and then submit.

I couldn't create a jsfiddle for my code, as I am using some old version of TinyMCE, so I couldn't replicate it. Here is my code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "exact",
    elements: "description",
    theme: "simple",
    height: '100px',
    width: '100%',
    onchange_callback: function(editor) {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        $("#" + editor.id).valid();
    }
});
```

Here is a similar [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtj35/) for something I created with the new version and it has the same problem in both Chrome and Mozilla. If I type something in the textarea and click submit, it is not shown unless I focus-out and submit again.

Answer (score 0):

I added `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` in submit handler before submitting the form and it solved the problem.
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtj35/3/).